# React: Values between {} of a multidimensional object not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Noob problem that I cannot resolve and couldn't find a solution. Values between curly braces not rendering in component Content and component Total. I checked the JSX rules but I'm missing something.

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const course = {
        name: 'Half Stack application development',
        parts: [
            {
                name: 'Fundamentals of React',
                exercises: 10
            },
            {
                name: 'Using props to pass data',
                exercises: 7
            },
            {
                name: 'State of a component',
                exercises: 14
            }
        ]
    }

    const Header = () => {
        //const course = 'Half Stack application development'
        return (<div>{course.name}</div>)
    }

    const Content = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Part1/>: {course.parts[[0].exercises]} exercises.<br />
                <Part2/>: {course.parts[[1].exercises]} exercises.<br />
                <Part3/>: {course.parts[[2].exercises]} exercises.<br />
            </div>
        )
    }

    const Part1 = () => {
        //const part1 = 'Fundamentals of React'
        return (<>{course.parts[[0].name]}</>)
    }

    const Part2 = () => {
        //const part2 = 'Using props to pass data'
        return (<>{course.parts[[1].name]}</>)
    }
    const Part3 = () => {
        //const part3 = 'State of a component'
        return (<>{course.parts[[2].name]}</>)
    }

    const Total = () => {
        //const exercises1 = 10
        //const exercises2 = 7
        //const exercises3 = 14
        return(
            <div>
                Number of exercises: {course.parts[[0].exercises]+ course.parts[[1].exercises] + course.parts[[2].exercises]}.
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header></Header>
            <Content></Content>
            <Total></Total>

        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

The above script render this on the browser, values should appear before ": exercises" in the lines 2,3,4 :

```
Half Stack application development
: exercises.
: exercises.
: exercises.
Number of exercises: NaN.
```

Comment: Your array index access syntax is wrong (all of them). `{course.parts[[0].exercises]}` must be `{course.parts[0].exercises}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `accessors` are wrong. You are currently accessing your `course` parts like

`course.parts[[index].exercises]` - This will result in `undefined` and adding `undefined` will result in `NaN`.

You need to access the `parts` like below :-

`course.parts[index].exercises`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {

    const course = {
        name: 'Half Stack application development',
        parts: [
            {
                name: 'Fundamentals of React',
                exercises: 10
            },
            {
                name: 'Using props to pass data',
                exercises: 7
            },
            {
                name: 'State of a component',
                exercises: 14
            }
        ]
    }


    const Header = () => {

        //const course = 'Half Stack application development'

        return(
            <div>
                {course.name}
            </div>

        )
    }

    const Content = () => {


        return(
            <div>
                <Part1/>: {course.parts[0].exercises} exercises.<br />
                <Part2/>: {course.parts[1].exercises} exercises.<br />
                <Part3/>: {course.parts[2].exercises} exercises.<br />
            </div>
        )
    }

    const Part1 = () => {
        //const part1 = 'Fundamentals of React'
        return (
            <>
                {course.parts[0].name}
            </>
        )
    }

    const Part2 = () => {
        //const part2 = 'Using props to pass data'
        return (
            <>
                {course.parts[1].name}
            </>
        )
    }
    const Part3 = () => {
        //const part3 = 'State of a component'
        return (
            <>
                {course.parts[2].name}
            </>
        )
    }

    const Total = () => {

        //const exercises1 = 10
        //const exercises2 = 7
        //const exercises3 = 14

        return(
            <div>
                Number of exercises: {course.parts[0].exercises+ course.parts[1].exercises + course.parts[2].exercises}.
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
           
            <Header></Header>
            <Content></Content>
            <Total></Total>

        </div>
    )

}

export default App;
```